# How can I send a PDF file over a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, http, https

I opened a file in binary format and extracted this file as String. After, I  tried to send it as HTTP reply. Finally, it looks like this:

```
ptr->Sendall((char*)"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
ptr->Sendall((char*)"Content-Type: pdf/html\r\n");
ptr->Sendall((char*)"Content-Length: 16384\r\n");
ptr->Sendall((char*)"\r\n");
ptr->Sendall((char*)wholeString.c_str());
ptr->Sendall((char*)"\r\n\r\n");
```

Content length is equal to the total size of the String.

I got an error in Google Chrome Web Browser: *cannot load pdf file*.

Comment: Why are there so many casts going on here? Are you trying to strip off the `const char*` part?

Comment: If your PDF file contains any nul bytes then `ptr->Sendall((char*)wholeString.c_str());` is going to result in truncated output.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary files by definition may contain characters that preclude them from being represented as C strings. The first NUL byte you hit will end the string prematurely and those appear *frequently* in all kinds of files.

`std::string` can represent these just fine. `c_str()` will return a pointer to the complete data, but you'll have to treat it as a raw buffer, not a C string, and supply the length to your `SendAll` type function as well.

It'd probably be better to make `SendAll` take either `const char*` or `const std::string&` as an argument.

Comment: Omg was that actually that easy? Thanks!

Comment: Also, `pdf/html` is the wrong media type for a PDF file, use `application/pdf` instead. Also, don't hard-code the `Content-Length` value, use `wholeString.size()` instead.